# How to loop list variable in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to apply random colors to the list view generated widgets in flutter.
here is the example.

this is a list view generated list , and different colors on each widget.

[image]

here is how I did that

```
ListView.separated(
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: docList.length,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                final data = docList[index];
                return Row(
                  children: [
                    DocLIstCard(
// here is the color list to apply different colors to each of the generated widget.
                      backgroundColor: AppColors.gradientIndex[index], 
                      category: data.sectionName,
                      docImage: data.image,
                      docName: data.name,
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return const SizedBox(width: 20);
              },
            ),
```

and here is the `AppColors.gradientIndex[index]`'s variable

```
 static const gradientIndex = [
    LinearGradient(
      begin: Alignment.topLeft,
      end: Alignment.bottomRight,
      colors: [Color(0xFF111A8A), Color(0xFFB1008A)],
    ),
    LinearGradient(
      begin: Alignment.topLeft,
      end: Alignment.bottomRight,
      colors: [Color(0xFFE97000), Color(0xFFB1008A)],
    ),
    LinearGradient(
      begin: Alignment.topLeft,
      end: Alignment.bottomRight,
      colors: [Color(0xFF111A8A), Color(0xFFB1008A)],
    ),
    LinearGradient(
      begin: Alignment.topLeft,
      end: Alignment.bottomRight,
      colors: [Color(0xFFE97000), Color(0xFFB1008A)],
    ),
  ];
```

if there are 1000 of widgets, I've to write the colors list 1000 times, so how can I loop this???

Comment: try `backgroundColor: AppColors.gradientIndex[index % AppColors.gradientIndex.length],`

Comment: @mmcdon20 if you do that you will get out of range exception, for instance, if the index is 20: 20 / 4 = 5, 5 is out of range in the `gradientIndex` list

Comment: @FabiánBardecio No, it will not get an out of range exception. The code I suggested uses mod (%) not division, `20 % 4 = 0` and `0` is not out of range of the list, nor will it be out of range with any other value for index.

Comment: Oh mb, you're right, didn't notice the %, that works as expected if you want to iterate the list of gradients, it's not random though

Comment: @FabiánBardecio no it isn't random, it will produce a repeating (aka looped) pattern that repeats the `gradientIndex` list. To be honest, from reading the question I'm not 100% certain if what he wants is a random selection or a looped pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use 2 different gradient, simple use odd or even number based on your index

```
DocLIstCard(
// here is the color list to apply different colors to each of the generated widget.
                      backgroundColor: getGradient(index), 
                      category: data.sectionName,
                      docImage: data.image,
                      docName: data.name,
                    ),

LinearGradient getGradient (int index) {
 if(index.isEven){
      return LinearGradient(
      begin: Alignment.topLeft,
      end: Alignment.bottomRight,
      colors: [Color(0xFF111A8A), Color(0xFFB1008A)],
    ),
    }
    else {
      return LinearGradient(
      begin: Alignment.topLeft,
      end: Alignment.bottomRight,
      colors: [Color(0xFFE97000), Color(0xFFB1008A)],
    ),
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dart math library to get a random number, just like this:

```
import 'dart:math';

final colorListIndex = Random().nextInt(4);
```

This will return a random number between 0 and 3, which you can then use as the index for the `AppColors.gradientIndex[index]` list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ListView.separated(
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: docList.length,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                final data = docList[index];
                return Row(
                  children: [
                    DocLIstCard(
// here is the color list to apply different colors to each of the generated widget.
                      backgroundColor: AppColors.gradientIndex[Random().nextInt(4)], 
                      category: data.sectionName,
                      docImage: data.image,
                      docName: data.name,
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return const SizedBox(width: 20);
              },
            ),
```